# IntelliJ `introduce parameter` shortcut on macOS brings up the preferences

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I have had this issue for a while, and now, after a fresh install of macOS I am plagued with it again, so, I am sure this isn't the result of some custom program running on the machine. I only have macOS Big Sur and IntelliJ IDEA (I had Catalina before with the same results).

Whenever I try to refactor code to introduce a new parameter using <kbd>Command-Option-P</kbd>, the preferences window pops up. This is beyond annoying, and I would rather not throw away years of muscle memory by remapping my extract parameter shortcut to something else.

Has anyone experienced this, and if so, what is the way to fix this?

Comment: Looks like a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-232003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @CrazyCoder who looked into this.

This is a known issue with the "ABC - Extended" keyboard selection on the macOS. I like this keyboard for the range of optional characters it gives me. But apparently, there is a known issue that prevents correct behavior in this case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-242986